# Vertical lines not complete in multicolumn table

Tags: tables, formatting, multicolumn

the vertical lines of my first row aren't joining my \toprule despite having specified vertical separators in the multicolumn command. Please help!

```
\begin{table*}[!h]\centering 
    \ra{0.8} 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|  c  c  c  c  c   c  c | c  c  c| }
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Blast facing side} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Rear face of plate}\\ 
        Plate & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{Deposition of burned material} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Dome inner surface} & Darkened & Ring around & Lines next \\ 
        & None & Fine & Moderate & Dense & Smooth & Dimples & Cross hatch & dome & dome & to dome \\ 
        \midrule
        BC50SOD & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        BC60SOD &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        BC75SOD &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        36C50SOD &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        36C60SOD &  &  & $\checkmark$  &   &  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$  & $\checkmark$ \\ 
        36C75SOD &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$  & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$  \\ 
        36C80SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ \\ 
        36C90SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$ \\ 
        36C100SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$ \\ 
        36C120SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$ &  \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
    \caption{caption} 
    \label{tab:restults} 
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the `\ra` command? Please always post full compilable posts.

Comment: `\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using booktabs, which should not be used with vertical rules if you want professional-looking tables.

The reason for this behaviour comes the fact that these rules add some vertical padding around them which breaks vertical rules. If you want to have full vertical rules, you have to delete this padding, adding

```
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
```

but you lose one of the main interests of `booktabs`.

You can replace this padding loading `cellspace`, which  allows to define a *minimal*  vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells, or `makecell` which allows to *add* a fixed spacing at the top and bottom of cells and, incidentally, also defines lines of variable thickness.

Comment: Thanks this seems to do the trick for the most part. There are still very tiny little gaps at the top. But of course now all my other tables are ruined!

Comment: You can make the changes local to this table: the changes need not be in the preamble.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\hline` instead of `\toprule` and `\midrule` or simply do not use vertical lines at all!

```
\def\arraystretch{0.8}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|  c  c  c  c  c   c  c | c  c  c| }
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Blast facing side} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Rear face of plate}\\ 
        Plate & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{Deposition of burned material} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Dome inner surface} & Darkened & Ring around & Lines next \\ 
        & None & Fine & Moderate & Dense & Smooth & Dimples & Cross hatch & dome & dome & to dome \\ 
        \hline
        BC50SOD & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        BC60SOD &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        BC75SOD &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        36C50SOD &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
        36C60SOD &  &  & $\checkmark$  &   &  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$  & $\checkmark$ \\ 
        36C75SOD &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$  & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$  \\ 
        36C80SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ \\ 
        36C90SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$ \\ 
        36C100SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$ \\ 
        36C120SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$ &  \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Still have the same problem when using \hline. I'm a big fan of not using vertical lines but this particular table becomes impossible to read without them!

Comment: see my edited example that it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use vertical rules compatible with the rules of `booktabs` (even if this is not in the spirit of `booktabs`) you may use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. Remark that in that environment, you must *not* put back the vertical rules (with `|`) in the instructions `\multicolumn`.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!h]\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|  c  c  c  c  c   c  c | c  c  c| }
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Blast facing side} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Rear face of plate}\\ 
    Plate & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Deposition of burned material} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Dome inner surface} & Darkened & Ring around & Lines next \\ 
    & None & Fine & Moderate & Dense & Smooth & Dimples & Cross hatch & dome & dome & to dome \\ 
    \midrule
    BC50SOD & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    BC60SOD &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    BC75SOD &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    36C50SOD &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    36C60SOD &  &  & $\checkmark$  &   &  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$  & $\checkmark$ \\ 
    36C75SOD &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$  & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$  \\ 
    36C80SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ \\ 
    36C90SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$ \\ 
    36C100SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$ \\ 
    36C120SOD & &  & $\checkmark$ &  &  &  & $\checkmark$ &  & $\checkmark$ &  \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular} 
\caption{caption} 
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]