# My table corners are not connected. how to solve this issue

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{4.25em}|p{15.125em}|p{12.315em}|p{8.565em}|}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Variables} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Formula} & \textbf{Source} \\
    \midrule
    Credit Risk & A borrower is unable to repay the loan or interest on the loan is termed as credit risk. & Non-performing loan  / Total Loan & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\
    \midrule
    GDP Growth & GDP (Gross Domestic Product) growth measures how fast an economy is growing by comparing GDP of two quarters. & (Current year growth rate - Previous year growth rate) / Current year growth rate & (Boudriga, Taktak, \& Jellouli, 2010; Djiogap \& Ngomsi, 2012) \\
    \midrule
    Inflation Rate Growth & The rate at which prices of goods increases overtime decreasing the value of money. & (Current price index - Previous year price index / Previous year price index) *100 & (I. Khan et al., 2018) \\
    \midrule
    Interest Rate & The percentage amount charged by the bank for lending money to the party. & Interest = (Principal + Annual Rate + Loan Period) / 100 & (Hui et al., 2017)\\
    \midrule
    Capital Adequacy Ratio & It is a measure of bank's total available capital divided by risk weighted assets.  & Total capital / Risk-weighted asset & (Boudriga et al., 2010; Kasana \& Naveed, 2016; Poudel, 2012) \\
    \midrule
    Loan to Total Asset Ratio & The ratio checks the of banks' assets by taking outstanding loans as a percentage of its assets. & (Total Outstanding Debt / Total Assets) *100 & (Ahmadyan, 2018) \\
    \midrule
    Loan to Deposit Ratio & This ratio checks the liquidity of a bank through comparison of its total loans and total deposits. & Total loan / Total deposits & (Kasana \& Naveed, 2016) \\
    \midrule
    Return on Assets & It is to check the profitability of banks & Total Income / Total Assets & (Boudriga 2010; Kasana,Naveed,2016)\\
    \midrule
    Bank Size & Natural logarithm of total assets of bank in time t. & Log of bank assets & (Garr, 2013; Kasana \& Naveed, 2016) \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. This is by design, you're using `booktabs`, and the rules from that package is meant to be used without vertical rules. Read the `booktabs` manual (you can find it e.g. on texdoc.net), there is some discussion about this there. I'd recommend not using the vertical rules at all, but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335633

Comment: I am new user i dont know how to deal with this issue can you solve this issue for me\\

Comment: Off-topic: The formula for the GDP growth rate is wrong.

Comment: As Thorbjørn says, don't use the vertical lines with the rules from `booktabs`, thus remove the `|`'s from the first line of your example. As already mentioned, it is my design that the rules don't work with vertical lines.

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself -- and even more so your readers -- a big favor by omitting all vertical lines and most horizontal lines. The result of this change will be a table that has a much more open "look" and literally *invites* readers to linger and spend some time taking in the information you've assembled.

Aside: I've fixed your formula for GDP growth; quite a few other variable definitions and formulas need to be fixed as well. E.g., one is usually interested in the inflation rate, not the growth rate of the inflation rate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Variable Definitions\strut}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\begin{tabular}{@{} P{5.25em}P{15.125em}P{12.315em}P{8.565em} @{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Variables} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Formula} & \textbf{Source} \\
    \midrule
    Credit Risk & A borrower is unable to repay the loan or interest on the loan is termed as credit risk. & Non-performing loan\slash Total Loan &  \\
    \addlinespace
    GDP Growth & GDP (Gross Domestic Product) growth measures how fast an economy is growing by comparing GDP of two quarters. & (Current year GDP~$-$ Previous year GDP)\slash Current year GDP & Boudriga, Taktak, \& Jellouli, 2010; Djiogap \& Ngomsi, 2012 \\
    \addlinespace
    Inflation Rate Growth & The rate at which prices of goods increases overtime decreasing the value of money. & (Current price index~$-$ Previous year price index\slash Previous year price index) *100 & I. Khan et al., 2018 \\
    \addlinespace
    Interest Rate & The percentage amount charged by the bank for lending money to the party. & Interest = (Principal + Annual Rate + Loan Period)\slash 100 & Hui et al., 2017\\
    \addlinespace
    Capital Adequacy Ratio & It is a measure of bank's total available capital divided by risk weighted assets.  & Total capital\slash Risk-weighted asset & Boudriga et al., 2010; Kasana \& Naveed, 2016; Poudel, 2012 \\
    \addlinespace
    Loan to Total Asset Ratio & The ratio checks the of banks' assets by taking outstanding loans as a percentage of its assets. & (Total Outstanding Debt\slash Total Assets) *100 & Ahmadyan, 2018 \\
    \addlinespace
    Loan to Deposit Ratio & This ratio checks the liquidity of a bank through comparison of its total loans and total deposits. & Total loan\slash Total deposits & Kasana \& Naveed, 2016 \\
    \addlinespace
    Return on Assets & It is to check the profitability of banks & Total Income\slash Total Assets & Boudriga 2010; Kasana \& Naveed, 2016\\
    \addlinespace
    Bank Size & Natural logarithm of total assets of bank in time $t$. & Log of bank assets & Garr, 2013; Kasana \& Naveed, 2016 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to add vertical rules compatibles with `booktabs` (even if this is not in the spirit of `booktabs`), you can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. However, I think that the result is better without these rules.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{4.25em}p{15.125em}p{12.315em}p{8.565em}}[vlines]
    \toprule
    \textbf{Variables} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Formula} & \textbf{Source} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    Credit Risk & A borrower is unable to repay the loan or interest on the loan is termed as credit risk. &
    Non-performing loan  / Total Loan \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    GDP Growth & GDP (Gross Domestic Product) growth measures how fast an economy is growing by comparing GDP of
    two quarters. & (Current year growth rate - Previous year growth rate) / Current year growth rate & (Boudriga,
    Taktak, \& Jellouli, 2010; Djiogap \& Ngomsi, 2012) \tabularnewline 
    \midrule
    Inflation Rate Growth & The rate at which prices of goods increases overtime decreasing the value of money. &
    (Current price index - Previous year price index / Previous year price index) *100 & (I. Khan et al., 2018) \tabularnewline 
    \midrule
    Interest Rate & The percentage amount charged by the bank for lending money to the party. & Interest =
    (Principal + Annual Rate + Loan Period) / 100 & (Hui et al., 2017)\tabularnewline 
    \midrule
    Capital Adequacy Ratio & It is a measure of bank's total available capital divided by risk weighted assets.  &
    Total capital / Risk-weighted asset & (Boudriga et al., 2010; Kasana \& Naveed, 2016; Poudel, 2012) \tabularnewline 
    \midrule
    Loan to Total Asset Ratio & The ratio checks the of banks' assets by taking outstanding loans as a percentage
    of its assets. & (Total Outstanding Debt / Total Assets) *100 & (Ahmadyan, 2018) \tabularnewline 
    \midrule
    Loan to Deposit Ratio & This ratio checks the liquidity of a bank through comparison of its total loans and
    total deposits. & Total loan / Total deposits & (Kasana \& Naveed, 2016) \tabularnewline 
    \midrule
    Return on Assets & It is to check the profitability of banks & Total Income / Total Assets & (Boudriga 2010;
    Kasana,Naveed,2016)\tabularnewline 
    \midrule
    Bank Size & Natural logarithm of total assets of bank in time t. & Log of bank assets & (Garr, 2013; Kasana \&
    Naveed, 2016) \tabularnewline 
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```